# cannot connect mysql from stimulsoft

Tags: mysql, stimulsoft

If anybody could help regarding how to connect MySQL from Stimulsoft. I'm getting the following error message:

> Connection error: The database type is not supported by pure JavaScript.

Comment: Your question lacks any sort of real data with which other users can attempt to assist you. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question, providing more information.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is in the link on this message.
You should specify a data adapter. Usually this way:

```
StiOptions.WebServer.url = "http://example.com/data/handler.php";
```

You couldd get additional information on the [Connect to SQL Database](https://www.stimulsoft.com/en/documentation/online/programming-manual/reports_js_connect_to_mysql_and_ms_sql_database.htm) section of the Programming manual (the link form the error message)